# How do I make headerLargeTitle appear as large title when the component is a flat list

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a `FlatList` component and I want the title to be large.  I defined the navigator as follows

```
export const SamplerStackNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerLargeTitle: true,
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Flat List" options={{}} component={TheList} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

However, it just shows the small header.  I can scroll down manually to make the large header appear, but I want to make it appear large by default.

https://snack.expo.dev/@trajano/multi-tab-navigation-with-refresh

On the "Home" tab I have

[image]

When I switch to the other tab (the header is small by default)

[image]

You can pull it down and it will render to the size I want.

[image]

Comment: Which header are you talking about? I cannot see any header of react-navigation in both the tabs.

Comment: I added the screenshots does it clarify?

Comment: You can add a custom header with your design pattern that will be the best solution.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid by using the native logic where possible.

Comment: As far as I know, `headerLargeTitle` is not a valid property.

Comment: It's built into native stack navigator https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#api-definition  in the specs https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/tree/master/native-stack#headerlargetitle

Comment: Apparently this is a bug https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/649

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: OP is using native stack & not stack navigation from react-navigation.**

You can use https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/tree/master/native-stack#headertitlestyle property to style.

Supported style properties are

- fontFamily
- fontSize
- fontWeight
- color

---

The easiest solution that I can give is using the prop `headerTitleStyle` if you are using the built-in header.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlestyle

For custom, you can build your own element and style according to your needs.

Check out the live snack demo https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/custom-navigation-title

Answer (score 1):

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
          headerLargeTitle: true,
        }}
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

[Finde more details here for iOS](https://mobiledevtutorials.com/how-to-make-large-header/)